# Save external kraken API json in my Django database?

Tags: django, api, django-models, model, kraken.com

#### The context

I want to save json data from an external public kraken API in my Django database
Do you have any suggestion of (i) how can i get the json response working accordingly, and (ii) how can i afterwards save it in my django database?

If you have any ideas or tips I would be very grateful.

Thank you!

My view.py

```
from rest_framework import generics
from .serializers import KrakenSerializer
from kraken.models import Kraken
import requests

class KrakenList(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    
    serializer_class = KrakenSerializer
    queryset = Kraken.objects.all()

    def get_object(self):
        url = 'https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Time'
        r = requests.get(url, headers={'Content-Type':      
            'application/json'})
        kraken = r.json()
        return kraken
    
    def seed_kraken():
        for i in kraken:
            krakenss = Kraken(
                unixtime=i["unixtime"],
            )
            krakenss.save()
```

My urls.py

```
from .views import KrakenList
from django.urls import path

app_name = 'kraken'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', KrakenList.as_view(), name='listkraken'),
]
```

My serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from kraken.models import Kraken

class KrakenSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Kraken
        fields = ('unixtime',)
```

My models.py

```
from django.db import models
class Kraken(models.Model):
    unixtime = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

This the Django REST framework with wrong empty json answer:
[image]

This is how the json unixtime answer should look like in my Django REST framework
[image]

## The issue

Do you have any suggestion of (i) how can i get the json info working accordingly, and (ii) how can i afterwards save it in my django database?